# How to read many files and assign each file to the next variable?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am beginner in Scala, I have following question:
How to read more that one csv file and and assign each file to the next variable?
I know how the read one file:

```
val file_1.sc.textFile("/Users/data/urls_20170225")
```

I also know how to read many files:

```
val file_2.sc.textFile("/Users/data/urls_*")
```

But second way assign all data to one variables file_2, is something that I don't want to! I am looking for elegant way to do this in Spark Scala.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems that you'd create an indeterminate number of vals. This doesn't lend itself to Stream or Iterative processing. This seems like a small part of your overall solution, what are you actually trying to accomplish? (also, *vals* are not variables....)

Answer (score 0):

spark has no API to load multiple files into multiple RDD. What you can do is load them one by one into one List of RDD. Below is a sample code.

```
def main(arg: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val dir = """F:\Works\SO\Scala\src\main\resource"""
  val startsWith = """urls_""" // we will use this as the wildcard

  val fileList:List[File] = getListOfFiles(new File(dir))
  val filesRDD:  List[RDD[String]] = fileList.collect({
    case file: File if file.getName.startsWith(startsWith)=> spark.sparkContext.textFile(file.getPath)
  })
}

//Get all the individual file paths
def getListOfFiles(dir: File):List[File] = dir.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList
```

Comment: This solution looks really transparent I understand your solution, however I got an error: error: not found: type File

Comment: You will need to add this package `import java.io.File` .